# How can I make Django to save users using DynamoDB?

Tags: django, amazon-dynamodb, django-database

I can't find a way to configure DynamoDB as the database for my application, apparently there is no built-in way to configure DynamoDB as the ENGINE for the project, is there a solution to bring my users to a DynamoDB table?

I'm looking for a way to authenticate users and superusers withouth having to implement an authentication system to do this.

Comment: I would highly suggest thinking long and hard about using any NoSQL database for like 90% of things you'll be doing in Django. Also - looking for a way to authenticate users and superusers without implementing an auth system is a bad idea. There's a lot that goes into auth.

Comment: Why would you recommend that? About the auth system I mean I don't want to implement a system from zero, first of all creating a new system from zero will bring vulnerabilities and it'll take a good amount of time. What I want to know is if there is a built-in auth system for Django using DynamoDB that I am not aware of or if there is an alternative from a third-party that someone with experience using it would recommend.

Comment: Why would you use a NoSQL database? And yes you're right - I see now. Here's what I mean: unless you have a specific use case that can't work with a relational database, why not use a relational database that already has such a strong support ecosystem of all the packages you'll ever need, including auth?